# Losing Internet Connection, Other Devices Working Fine

Tags: internet-connection, wireless-router

I'm losing connection to the internet through my router even while others are playing online on a PS3 without a problem. I keep my connection to the router but have limited connectivity. I can reset the router and regain my connection for a time, but it will go again after a while (while the PS3 continues to work fine).

I've tried setting my IP to dynamic and static with no difference. Any thoughts on why this would be? It almost appears like the router is giving priority to other devices than the computer.

Comment: "It almost appears like the router is giving priority to other devices than the computer." - Did you confirm by disconnecting the PS3? Does your router have QOS features?

Comment: Manufacturer and model of your router?